# Meta Box plugin image_advanced not showing up on frontend

Tags: plugins, php, metabox

I'm using the [Meta Box](http://metabox.io/docs/) plugin on a site and am having trouble with one of the meta boxes options. I've got it working fine in the backend, but when I use it in a page template all i get on the front end is the word 'Array' displayed. Here is the code I'm using:

`<?php echo rwmb_meta('mostfilms_onesheet', 'type=image_advanced&size=full' ); ?>`

I'm not sure what to do here, I'm not a really well versed in PHP and there doesn't seem to be any documentation pertaining to the 'image_advanced' option.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I figures this out. Here is the code that worked:

`$images = rwmb_meta( 'mostfilms_onesheet', 'type=image_advanced&size=full' );
foreach ( $images as $image ) {
    echo "<img src='{$image['url']}' width='{$image['width']}' height='{$image['height']}' alt='{$image['alt']}' />";
}`